# How get client real IP when using nginx server in front of node as proxy

Tags: node.js, http, express, proxy, ip

I'n need to get client real IP address in nodeJs, when using nginx proxy server I always get my localhost(127.0.0.1). Can anyone help me to solv this problem? 
Here is my code

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  app.ipInfo = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
    req.connection.remoteAddress ||
    req.socket.remoteAddress ||
    req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
  next();
});
```

Comment: which proxy are you using ?

Comment: I have nginx server in front of node as proxy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In nginx if you want to pass through the IP address of the remote user to your backend web server you have to set `X-Forwarded-For` header to this remote ip, Like this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Comment: Yes it's, now the `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` header will contain the remote ip, you can just simplify your code to `app.ipInfo = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;`

Comment: my server configured like this  `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`

Comment: That should work too, it will append the remote ip to the existing ips in X-forwarded-For header, try to add this line `console.log(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'])`  in your middleware to see if we get the remote ip or not

Comment: And use `req.ipInfo = ...` instead of `app.ipInfo`

Comment: it returns ip  ::1

Comment: If you are trying to access web server from local machine, this is normal because all servers are hosted in local

Comment: ok, after setting X-Forwarded header in your nginx server, did you restart the server ? try `sudo service nginx retstart`